# Why is my CocoaPod not downloading the source from the specified URL?

Tags: ios, cocoapods, dependency-management, ios-frameworks

I have a zipped up iOS framework which I am trying to use via CocoaPods in a test application. I have added it in my github under releases. My podspec currently looks like :

```
Pod::Spec.new do |spec|
  spec.name             = "TestPod"
  spec.version          = "0.1"
  spec.license          = { :type => "MIT", :file => "LICENSE" }
  spec.homepage         = 'http://www.test.com'
  spec.author           = "test"
  spec.summary          = "test."
  spec.source           = { :http => "https://github.com/username/TestPod/releases/download/0.1/TestPod-0.1.zip"}
  spec.vendored_framework     = "TestPod-0.1/TestPod.framework"
  spec.ios.deployment_target = '8.0'
end
```

I'm using this directly in my Podfile with -

```
target 'TestApp' do
  pod 'TestPod', :git => 'https://github.com/username/TestPod/'
end
```

However, on doing a `pod install`, I found that the Zipped file `TestPod-0.1.zip` was neither downloaded nor was the framework added to my project. Can someone please advise me as to how I can get the Pod to download my framework?

Comment: If anyone wants to know, this can be fixed by using `:podspec` instead of `:git`

Comment: Thanks for the comment to your post!  I was following the blog article at https://eladnava.com/publish-a-universal-binary-ios-framework-in-swift-using-cocoapods/ and was stumped for hours before happening upon your answer of using :podspec

Comment: @gran_profaci -  **: podspec** is working fine but resource_bundles(nib, imeges) is empty. Any Idea why is it. If I am using **:path** then it doesn't download from source but able to get resource_bundles(nib, imeges)

Answer (score 1):

You must specify a git repo not just some arbitrary directory. So instead of using: `https://github.com/username/TestPod/` (a directory), you should pull the URL that you would use to clone the repo (the `HTTPS` path not `SSH`). This is probably `https://github.com/username/TestPod.git` in your case.

On Github this can generally be found on the top of the repo you want to use. If you are still having problems, please specify the actual repo you are trying to use.

Answer (score 0):

Your podfile should point to the repo.  So as your podfile (using the test repo you indicated for TTNew) should look like:

```
 pod 'TTNew', :git => 'https://github.com/aditya-tirodkar/TTNew.git'
```

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for the same trouble: add podspec to repo and do not use `:git => 'https://github.com/username/TestPod/'` part. So it will look like plain `pod 'TestPod'`.

Some info is [here](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/6402).

Why does it work — mystery :)

Answer (score 0):

I also just came across this issue and I was able to confirm that using `:podspec =>` to directly access the podspec file worked, but manually targeting the `main` branch with `:git =>` didn't. From the looks of it, `:git =>` clones the source code from the repo, but doesn't expect to have to perform the HTTP download.

Indeed I'm getting the feeling this isn't really an official way of doing this. The podspec needs to be pushed to a CocoaPods specs repo, and then pulled the traditional way for downloading via HTTP to work.

With this in mind (And because my own podspec wasn't one I wanted to officially publish on CocoaPods), I was able to solve this by making [my own private specs repo](https://guides.cocoapods.org/making/private-cocoapods.html) and then pushing the podspec there.

Making a private specs repo was insanely easy to do manually:

1. Make a new repo on GitHub called '/Specs'.
2. Push the podspec to the repo under the folder structure `<RepoName>/<TagVersion>/<RepoName>.podspec`
3. In the original `Podfile`, add the following to the top

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
source 'https://github.com/<MyAccount>/Specs.git'
```

From there, you can then just use `pod 'MyRepo'` in your Podfile, and it will pull from your private specs repo. Hope that helped!

Answer (score -1):

well, I have similar requirement and my pod install do not download my .zip file at http source (tried with git as well as to my http deployment server)

It works like champ with "google-cast-idk".

Any clue would be helpful.

Comment: your answer gives general idea how the question can be solved, but no concrete solution. Please consider to modify the answer!